# javascript audio syntax might be wrong?

Tags: javascript, audio

It doesn't play the sound. I've seen different syntax formulations for javascript audio and now I'm a little unsure about what is right and what is wrong. I'm guessing the issue is with the new Audio bit since I'm not sure if that's right. Thanks for the help.

```
var greenSound = new Audio('<https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3>');
    var redSound = new Audio('<https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3>');
    var blueSound = new Audio('<https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3>');
    var yellowSound = new Audio('<https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3>');
    var sounds = [greenSound, redSound, blueSound, yellowSound];
    var soundNums = [];


num = Math.floor(4*Math.random());
                    simon.push(moves[num]);
                    soundNums.push(num);
                    for(var i = 0; i < simon.length; i++)
                        {
                            $(simon[i]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
                            (sounds[soundNums[i]]).play();
                        }
```

Comment: whats simon ? ist just empty array ? `simon.push(moves[num]);`

Comment: var simon = [];
    var player = [];
    var green = $(".green-button"); 
    var red = $(".red-button");
    var blue = $(".blue-button");
    var yellow = $(".yellow-button");
    var num;
    var moves = [green, red, blue, yellow];

I'm not sure how to make it code in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine you have syntax issue in URL.

**From this:**

```
var mp3 = new Audio('<https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3>');
```

**To this:**

```
var mp3 = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
```